# The power of saying tehillim

Tags: tehilim-psalms, segulah

When I was starting to become observant, at the end of shacharis one day, someone asked me "are you finished with tehillim?". I told them I don't know what that is. They told me "if we knew what was happening in heaven while we are saying tehillim, we would be saying them all day non stop".

So, a few years later, I still would like to know what the power of tehillim is. What corrective action are we taking by saying them?

Comment: This booklet translates a collection of letters from the Previous Lubavitcher Rebbe on the subject of reciting Tehillim: http://hebrewbooks.org/15690

Comment: Very related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/64570/8775.

Answer (score 8):

At one point as a young student I was informed that a neighbor's wife had become seriously ill, and I began reciting a very lengthy regimen of Tehillim for her every morning after Shaharith, including sections of 119 spelling her name. This made me very late for Shi'ur on a frequent basis, and my Rav finally asked me why I was so late so often. When I told him why, he suggested that it would be better to interrupt my Tehillim to come to Shi'ur on time, because the source we have for the power of Tehillim is a Midrash that says that David HaMelech asked HaShem to receive Tehillim the way He receives Talmud Torah (ie., to make the recitation of Tehillim as powerful as Talmud Torah). The Midrash does not tell us whether or how HaShem responded. Hence, Talmud Torah is *at least* as powerful as Tehillim. Not to say Tehillim isn't powerful or important, just putting it in perspective. Talmud Torah KeNeged Kulam.

Comment: re: "The Midrash does not tell us whether or how HaShem responded." see http://books.google.com/books?id=NnyuhrzRDCMC&lpg=PP1&dq=treasury%20of%20chassidic%20tales&pg=PA602#v=onepage&q&f=false for a response

Comment: If I read that correctly, Kol SheKen?

Comment: read the second page

Comment: Hmm.... http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/752/5

Comment: FWIW, I hear it, but I don't love it.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin All that does is remove the proof from the second case. If the _lamdan_ had a mesorah on the first point, that still stands.

Comment: The Midrash does not contrast Tehillim with Torah study, but with Negaim and Ohalot (IIRC). It is certainly possible that the intent is that Tehillim also counts as Torah study. || Nor is the Midrash addressing using words of Psalms as prayers. It seems very likely that prayer beats Torah study; otherwise why pray, Cf. Megillah 16a || Ritual recitation of Psalms as a segulah, such as recitation to spell out a name is totally forbidden according to Rambam Hil. Avodah Zara (ch. 11) cf. http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/64570/8775.

Comment: At least some Rishonim understand כנגד כלם to mean the others listed in the Mishna, but not necessarily greater than all mitzvot.

Comment: @SethJ - The practice in many (if not all) Yeshivos is to, on rare occasions,  interrupt learning and have the entire Yeshiva say Tehillim, so it would seem that sometimes Tehillim can accomplish what learning cannot - even if generally speaking Torah is more powerful. The fact that one medicine is more powerful doesn't mean you don't need the second type of medicine as well - they may perform different functions which are both needed.

Comment: @mevaqesh, clearly, there are many who recite Tehillim specifically for illnesses.

Comment: @Jay, ok. You are welcome to post an answer.

Comment: @SethJ ok. whats your point?

Comment: @SethJ - I don't think what I wrote is relevant to this particular question. I was only addressing your point about Tehillim vs. Torah, which is something I don't think the questioner is asking about. And please don't misunderstand, I don't mean to be challenging the psak that your Rebbe gave you - I'm just saying it's not a black-and-white issue of which is 'better', and based on that only one should always be done, rather it seems to be a more complex issue.

Comment: @SethJ Your Rav's point is stated by the Nefesh Hachaim

Answer (score 7):

This individual was quoting the Tzemach Tzedek (3rd Lubavitcher Rebbe) who is quoted in [HaYom Yom 24th of Shvat](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/6074/jewish/Shvat-24.htm):

> "If you only knew the power that lies in the verses of Tehillim and their effects in the celestial heights, you would recite them all the time. Know that the chapters of Tehillim break through all barriers and soar aloft from level to level unimpeded. They intercede before the Master of the Universe and secure their effect with kindess and mercy."

In his diary ([see Tehillim Ohel Yosef Yitzchak p. 210](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=32596&pgnum=210)), the Rebbe Rayatz (6th Lubavitcher Rebbe) relates a story surrounding this statement that is to long for me to type.

The summary is as follows. The Tzemach Tzedek saw in a vision a very harsh decree against the Jewish people, especially the Torah community. Nothing could overturn in. The Tzemach Tzedek told his oldest son to get a minyan to say the entire book of Tehillim no later than 4am. For 53 days the minyan took place and then the Tzemach Tzedek had a vision of his grandfather the Alter Rebbe holding 53 books of tehillim smiling.

Comment: The story as told in Tehillim does not mention that Tzemach Tzedek had a vision after the decree was nullified. - English version http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=15690&pgnum=46

Answer (score 2):

The **Baal Shem Tov** stated that if **Psalm 119** is said every day, a person will be able to enter into a meditative state when talking to another and receive deep perceptions about that person.  *("Rabbi Nachman's Tikun Haklali" by Daniel A. Elias.)*

Comment: Seems terribly socially inconvenient.

Answer (score 1):

> It is well known that Dawid HaMelekh was the soul of all Israel, as written "The praise of Hashem shall my mouth speak and all
>   flesh shall bless His Holy Name." The reason it says the words "all
>   flesh" is meaning at any time (Yismah Yisrael, Parashat Eqeb). Meaning
>   whenever one is in need, he should pray Tehilim. The Semah Sedeq once
>   said that if we knew the strength of the Tehilim, and the Heavens we
>   would recite it every moment.Their actions make kindness and mercy
>   (ibid.). The Emeq HaMelekh writes (pg. 15) that the book of Tehilim
>   declines many stumbling blocks and some damages from him and his
>   household members, and his family as well. It makes great blessings
>   goodness and merits to him. It is also interesting that the Magen
>   U'Shemesh writes that Gimatria of the one hundred and fifty Pesuqim is
>   corresponding to the Gimatria of Pidion (redemption). 
>           The Midrash in Pinhas writes that whatever a person needs, he should recite Tehilim for it. (He should recite it consecutively) and
>   not stop for the Yehi Rason between the books of Tehilim, until he has
>   completed the entire Sefer. Through the Tehilim we bring closer the
>   redemption (Midrash Tehilim, Shir HaShirim). "Whoever recites Tehilim
>   every day, it is as if we fulfilled the entire Torah (Rabenu Efraim,
>   Parashat WeZot HaBerakha)." One who wants to have a connection with
>   Hashem, should recite Tehilim (Shala, Nazir 257). The Noam Elimelekh
>   writes that Tehilim have the possibility to make drastic changes and
>   there is no Sat-an or obstacle stopping them. The Shebut Ya'aqob
>   writes (Heleq Bet, Yoreh De'ah 44) that if one desires to make many
>   prayers, he should recite Tehilim, because it is leaning Torah, and
>   there are many good omens in it. Rabbi Haim Palagi writes (Minhagi
>   HaHabi"f 80) that one who recites Tehilim (and Brikat HaMazon) daily
>   lengthen their years and days. Rabbi Haim Palagi also writes that this
>   worlds stands upon Tehilim, and one redeems themselves from any
>   damages and redemption will come through the recitation of Tehilim
>   (Haqdama, Kol HaKatub LeHaim). One who recites Tehilim daily merits to
>   be under the Kise HaKabod (Chair of Honor). We have nothing greater
>   than Tehilim because contains everything (Shala). 
>            There are countless compliments and praises of the sacred and holy book of Tehilim, and one could go on and on upon its' praise, so
>   always remember, we can save many people from sickness or anything bad
>   by just reciting Tehilim!

From [here](http://yessodfoundation.blogspot.com/2011/02/reciting-tehilim-psalms-15.html).

Comment: `It is well known that Dawid HaMelekh was the soul of all Israel` What does that even mean?

Answer (score 0):

Your question addressed here: [The Incredible Power of Tehillim: Parts 1 & 2.](http://ajewishsoul.blogspot.com/2006/07/incredible-power-of-tehillim-parts-1-2.html)

> The 3rd Lubavitcher Rebbe, known as the Tzemach Tzedek said in the name of Rabbi Yehuda "Whatever Dovid Hamelech say’s [sic] in his book pertains to himself, to all of Israel and to all times.”
>
> “If one would only know the power of verses in Tehillim, and their effect on high, one would recite them continually. The verse of Tehillim transcend all barriers and ascend higher and higher, imploring the Master of the Universe, until they achieve results of kindness and mercy.” (Hayom Yom)

Comment: Some background around the link would be nice.

Comment: Please [edit] in a summary of the information in the linked resource than answers the question at hand.

Answer (score -1):

• Maharsha says that Tehillim brings one to fear of Hashem.

• Peleh Yoetz says, “One who routinely says Tehillim is protected from all harm befalling his house, his family etc. One who wishes to attach himself to Hashem and His praises should be connected to sefer Tehillim. We have a tradition that one who has a problem, or pain, or is going on the road, should read the entire Tehillim all day without stopping, with kavana and humbleness. He will see wonders. is tradition has been tried and tested (and works)."

• Tehillim protects you in this world and in the next.

• One who says Tehilim for forty days is saved from harmful events.

See [*All About Tehillim*](http://bit.ly/2cFM7D2)

Comment: Please [edit] in a summary of the information in the linked resource than answers the question at hand.

Comment: The link does not work.