# Is it OK to say Tehillim whenever the inspiration strikes?

Tags: tehilim-psalms, speech-talking

Barring a situation where prayer would be forbidden like an unclean area, is it OK to say Tehillim anywhere, at any time, even repeating the same chapter multiple times in succession?

Comment: why would you think that it is not OK?

Comment: @C.BenYosef I'm wondering if it might violate using God's name unnecessarily or something of that nature, it's hard to explain :/

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/5527/759

Answer (score 10):

The Tzemach Tzedek (Lubavitch) wrote, that if we only knew the power of saying Psalms, and the positive spiritual effect they had we would say them constantly!

See this video: [Hayom Yom Shevat 24.](http://www.chabad.org/multimedia/media_cdo/aid/1774078/jewish/Reflections-on-Hayom-Yom-Shevat-24.htm)

And the text can be found [here](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/6074/jewish/Hayom-Yom-Shvat-24.htm)

Comment: That would seem to be quite an unfortunate scenario as knowledge of Torah would quickly be lost.

Comment: @DoubleAA Tehilim is very much a part of Torah. At any rate, if one is not spending their time amassing Torah knowledge, Tehilim is an excellent way to spend one's time. (aside from the time spent doing good deeds etc.)

Comment: Tehillim is a part of Tanach, and saying its words is certainly better than many other activities, but that doesn't make the ideal world into one where everyone just sits and says Tehillim over and over again.

Comment: @DoubleAA I would say it's just a turn of phrase trying to emphasize the power and holiness of saying Tehillim, not C'V that it's a substitute for the mitzvah of learning Torah.

Comment: @Izzy Maybe. See also http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/17167/759.

Comment: @DoubleAA Yes, I agree with Izzy. Also, we should really debate the issue in another question e.g. the value of saying Tehillim, feel free to open another question where you can agree or disagree on the Tzemach Tzedek's assertion. The point of the answer was to give the questioner a reference to the importance of saying Tehillim.

Comment: Well, the point of the question was to discuss if tehillim are allowed to be said whenever.

Comment: @DoubleAA Perhaps you can post an additional answer.